# Satisfying conditions in a ternary operator

Tags: c, printf, operator-keyword

Could you possibly tell me what condition should be satisfied for the ternary (`:?`) operator in the code below to print `****` and what for `+++++++`?:

```
printf( "%s\n", count % 2 ? "****" : "++++++++" );
```

Comment: What do you think? Did you try with different values of `count` to see what it prints?

Comment: Have you tried to answer this question personally before posting to stackoverflow?

Answer (score 0):

the % operator is the modulo operator: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation

This part:

```
 count % 2 ? "****" : "++++++++"
```

means (in pseudo code)

```
 if count is not even 
    return ****
 else
    return ++++++++
```

this part

```
printf("%s\n", 'string')
```

means (in pseudo code)

```
replace %s with string and print with a newline character
```

to put it all together its something like:

```
if count is not even 
    print **** with a newline character
else
    print ++++++++ with a newline character
```

Comment: That's wrong actually. `2 % 2` will evaluate to false.

Comment: yeah, I was editing the answer - I noticed that after I wrote the answer

Comment: @Jonathan Just out of curiosity, why did you remove the formatting in [your attempted edit of the question](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5997062)?

Comment: @admdrew - wasn't aware that I had